# Rename files with Static text after removing '0'

Tags: powershell

I have few files starting with zero like this

000145
000029

I am able to remove the zero for the file name with this script and also want to add _16 in the filename while renaming and the file should be like this 145_16 or 29_16.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 0*
$files |Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.TrimStart('0')+"_16"}
```

But after renaming the file is showing the .jpg also in the filename. Here is the example

145.jpg_16 or 29.jpg_16

Can anyone please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Name` property includes the filename extension. Use `.BaseName` and `.Extension` separately:

```
$files | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.TrimStart('0')+'_16' + $_.Extension }
```